# Match specific not between tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have some regex expressions to put content between tag, as seen on result. If i apply the same regex expressions on the resulted text i will get tags inside tags...

ORIGINAL CONTENT:

> Lorem ipsum 123456 dolor sit @twitter amet,
>   consectetur adipiscing elit example .

RESULT:

> Lorem ipsum [tel]123456[/tel] dolor sit [tw]@twitter[/tw]
>   amet, consectetur adipiscing elit [a]example[/a] .

RESULT SECOND TIME:

> Lorem ipsum [tel][tel]123456[/tel][/tel] dolor sit
>   [tw][tw]@twitter[/tw][/tw] amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
>   [a][a]example[/a][/a] .

What to put in my regex expressions so that will not match if content is between any [] and [/] ?

Comment: Try adding `(?!\[\/[^]]*])` to the end of your regex patterns.

Comment: The answer below is a workaround, not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

```
(?:[0-9]+|twitter|consectetur)(?![0-9a-z]*\[\/[a-z]+\])
```

Replace with: `[xx]$0[/XX]`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- find all the strings of numbers, the word `twitter`, and the word `consectetur`. I selected these substrings to illustrate the regular expression but these could be replaced with other strings.
- verify that the word is not already followed by a close tag
- avoid edge cases

  - the construct `[0-9+]` will match `2345` which is in the source string but it may already be wrapped by tags
  - matching `twitter` without the leading `@` still has a trailing tag

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/lW2pY6/1

**Sample Text**

> 123456 Lorem ipsum [tel]123456[/tel] dolor sit [tw]@twitter[/tw] amet, consectetur adipiscing elit [a]example[/a]

**Sample After Replacement**

> [XX]123456[/XX] Lorem ipsum [tel]123456[/tel] dolor sit [tw]@twitter[/tw] amet, [XX]consectetur[/XX] adipiscing elit [a]example[/a]

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    twitter                  'twitter'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    consectetur              'consectetur'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9a-z]*                any character of: '0' to '9', 'a' to 'z'
                             (0 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \[                       '['
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z]+                   any character of: 'a' to 'z' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \]                       ']'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```